# Python script to convert from UTF-8 to ASCII

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to write a script in python to convert utf-8 files into ASCII files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# *-* coding: iso-8859-1 *-*

import sys
import os

filePath = "test.lrc"
fichier = open(filePath, "rb")
contentOfFile = fichier.read()
fichier.close()

fichierTemp = open("tempASCII", "w")
fichierTemp.write(contentOfFile.encode("ASCII", 'ignore'))
fichierTemp.close()
```

When I run this script I have the following error :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xef in position 13:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

I thought that can ignore error with the ignore parameter in the encode method. But it seems not.

I'm open to other ways to convert.

Comment: The problem is that you never decode in the first place.

Comment: You got the error because the character doesn't exist in the ASCII character set, so it can't be converted. Sometimes you can map the UTF8 character to a closest visual-fit character in ASCII, such as `é` to `e`, but that can change the meaning of words. You have to decide if that path will work for your application.

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea!!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
data="UTF-8 DATA"
udata=data.decode("utf-8")
asciidata=udata.encode("ascii","ignore")
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad recipe for data loss.

Comment: You should expect data loss if you wish to convert from a 8bit encoding to 7bit.

Comment: I ignored that I have to decode first. It works now thanks. To answer to the questions, I want to do this because my MP3 player can only display lyrics files encoded in ASCII.

Comment: You can have a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/517974/1463812

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?` for the second line with python 3.10.4

Answer (score 9):

```
import codecs

 ...

fichier = codecs.open(filePath, "r", encoding="utf-8")

 ...

fichierTemp = codecs.open("tempASCII", "w", encoding="ascii", errors="ignore")
fichierTemp.write(contentOfFile)

 ...
```

Answer (score 6):

UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. Either your UTF-8 file is ASCII, or it can't be converted without loss.

Comment: I think he's aware of that, otherwise he wouldn't be trying to use `'ignore'`.

Comment: @Ignacio True. But this one left me wondering what the asker is trying to achieve. They could be cargo-culting, or maybe their need is best met by something like urlencode, or being lossy is just acceptable.

Comment: I am afraid of the cargo-culting. Culling all characters that you don’t have an appreciation for is really insensitive.

Comment: @Ignacio: Imagine being addressed as *Vzquez-Abrams*. :(

Comment: @tchrist: That's why I never use it.

Comment: Sometimes you can convert UTF8 to ASCII without losses, for instance, single quotes or apostrophes, in few other cases - arithmetic operations - both available as UTF8 long encoding and ASCII single symbol.