# TypeError: expected string or buffer for regex re.search()

Tags: python, html, regex, python-requests, encode

I am pulling an HTML page with [requests](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python-requests.org%2F&ei=bFgjVb_eG8mosAXQrYNI&usg=AFQjCNFyAH9fsxdKUHgs_F_P-ZQ_-_P1nw&sig2=xvAu0IkscuRFzArvdZWREw&bvm=bv.89947451,d.b2w) and trying to extract a link from it using regex but i keep getting TypeError: expected string or buffer.

Code:

```
r = requests.get('https://reddit.com/r/spacex')
subreddit=r.text
match=re.search(r'(<li class="first"><a href=")(.+)(")', subreddit)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(2))
```

However if i take a chunk of the HTML and hardcode it as a string then my code works:

```
subreddit='<li class="first"><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/3115xw/latest_update_pic_of_slc4_pad_shows_ln2_tankage/"'
r = requests.get('https://reddit.com/r/spacex')
match=re.search(r'(<li class="first"><a href=")(.+)(")', subreddit)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(2))
```

I also tried doing

```
 match=re.search(r'(<li class="first"><a href=")(.+)(")', str(subreddit))
```

as suggest around here but that didn't work. I did not receive any errors but match.group(2) never printed the link.

Comment: It might be an encoding issue.  Check what type of encoding is being used for the HTML block.  Also, checkout BeautifulSoup4 (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  It's an HTML parser.

Comment: Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for HTML parsing.

Comment: I did a lot of searching on that as well but i'm really not sure. I did print(r.encode) and it printed UTF-8. Does that help? Edit: i realize now i could have used beautifulsoup but i'm really trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: your code works for me..

Comment: Try encoding it as ascii (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299675/python-script-to-convert-from-utf-8-to-ascii) and see if that works.  I'm almost positive I've had this issue before when writing a scraper.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you have multiple lines in `subreddit` separated by `'\n'` when you do `subreddit=r.text`. Hence your regex doesn't search beyond first `'\n'`

- try adding [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) option. OR
- search in each line of `for line in subreddit.split('\n')`

.

```
r = requests.get('https://reddit.com/r/spacex')
subreddit=r.text
print('subreddit:' + subreddit)
subreddit.split('\n')
```

If the code above produces `NoneType has no split()` then there is something wrong with your `requests.get()`.. It's not returning anything.. may be a proxy?

Post the output of this code anyway..

Comment: first one produced the same error, second one produced a  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `BeautifulSoup`, it will be a lot easier for you:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://reddit.com/r/spacex').read())
>>> for x in soup.find_all("li", "first")
...     print x.a['href']
```

Or you can simply do:

```
>>> soup.select('a[href="https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/3115xw/latest_update_pic_of_slc4_pad_shows_ln2_tankage/"]')
[<a class="comments may-blank" href="https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/3115xw/latest_update_pic_of_slc4_pad_shows_ln2_tankage/">10 comments</a>]
```

Comment: is your code satisfies this `<li class="first"><a href="` condition?

Comment: yeaa @AvinashRaj is showed him to extract the link, the match is now, so easy

Comment: i think the above code will print all the href links of a tags which are present inside the `li` tag where the `class` = `first` , i won't do nothing with the position of anchor tags. But OP wants the immediate anchor tag which follows the li tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running python 3.4 and this  code which uses regex works for me.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('https://reddit.com/r/spacex')
>>> re.search(r'(<li class="first"><a href=")(.+?)(")', r.text).group(2)
'https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/31p51d/tory_bruno_posts_infographic_of_ula_vs_spacex/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't using `re` like you asked about, but in a similar vein to the `BeautifulSoup` answer above:

Can you use `PyQuery` along with `requests`?

Is this the links you're looking for?

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery as PyQuery

r = requests.get('https://reddit.com/r/spacex')
subreddit = r.text
pyq_to_parse = PyQuery(subreddit)
result = pyq_to_parse(".first").find("a")
print result
```