# Convert encoding of a text file from utf-8 to ansi or unicode in python

Tags: python, text, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I have a text file with utf-8 encoding. I want to change it's unicode to ANSI or unicode automatically in python.
Is it possible? 
How can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299675/python-script-to-convert-from-utf-8-to-ascii

Comment: A precision: **unicode** is a characters set; **utf8** is a codec (an algorithm) used to encode Unicode characters.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, but when in windows we want to save as a text file, in encoding options we can see both utf-8 and unicodes.!?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/1513933 for a clear description of what is ANSI charset.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15128103/1513933 to have a clear description of what is Unicode charset.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
#read input file
with codecs.open('USERS.CSV', 'r', encoding = 'latin-1') as file:
lines = file.read()  

#write output file
with codecs.open('1_UserPython.CSV', 'w', encoding = 'utf_8_sig') as file:
file.write(lines)
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert a file from utf8 to cp1252:

```
import io

with io.open(src_path, mode="r", encoding="utf8") as fd:
    content = fd.read()
with io.open(dst_path, mode="w", encoding="cp1252") as fd:
    fd.write(content)
```